# Representing hierarchical data in Google Spreadsheets

Tags: google-sheets

Smartsheet.com allows hierarchical representation of data in a single sheet {without having to use [adjacency lists](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_list)}. [Example](http://help.smartsheet.com/customer/portal/articles/504734-hierarchy-indenting-outdenting-rows).

Do Google Spreadsheets support hierarchical (nested) data in a single spreadsheet, without using adjacency list?

If not, what alternative approaches are supported by Google Spreadsheets?

Comment: As far as I can tell, [not currently](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/pm4Gd4O_Bm0). You can write a script to hide/show rows [like this example for columns](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/77853/i-need-to-hide-show-a-group-of-columns-in-google-sheets-in-a-simple-way) - but that is perhaps too finnicky.

Comment: whether it is supported at all

Answer (score 1):

Not supported but technically can do workarounds:

- For columns - put in separate columns and use JOIN(" "; [columns to join]), i.e. separator could be just space or some other symbol. According sample: Column A for Administration; Column B for 2nd level; Column C for join("_"; A:B) should produce nested list.
- For rows - use Autofilter

Comment: The question says "without using adjacency lists". The use of JOIN requires adjacency lists.